# Как ускорить сохранение .jpg в Android?

Tags: android, оптимизация, камера

Я разрабатываю приложение (на Android 4.0.3), которое делает серию снимков при нажатии на кнопку и сохраняет их в формате jpg на карту памяти телефона. На данный момент серия из 30 снимков выполняется (делаем их автоматически и сохраняем на карту) за 15-18 сек., использую фронтальную камеру, мне необходимо добиться результата в 2-3 сек. Есть два вопроса:

1. Это возможно сделать?
2. Если да, то как и что нужно оптимизировать, код приложил.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {

        try {
            if(!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, String.format("%d.jpg", count)));
            outStream.write(data[0]);
            outStream.flush();
            count++;
            if(count==30) {
                outStream.close();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + new File(dir, String.format("%d.jpg", count)).getAbsolutePath());
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(count<30) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, mPictureCallback);
        } else {
            m_Time = System.currentTimeMillis() - m_Time;
            mLog.setText("Время: " + Long.toString(m_Time) + "мс");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код метода `onPreExecute`, чтобы видеть, как инициализируются все значения.

Comment: @OleGG `
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calibration);


        mContext = this;
        mCamera = openCamera (); //1
        if (mCamera == null) { //2
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opening camera failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        preview = new CameraPreview (this, mCamera); //3
        mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout); //4
        mFrame.addView(preview, 0);

    }`

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо было бы завернуть `FileOutputStream` в `BufferedOutputStream`:

```
outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, String.format("%d.jpg", count))));
```

Тогда запись в файл будет вестись не побайтно, а блоками. Можно будет избавиться и от `outStream.flush()`, он не так сильно тут нужен, но быстродействие может ухудшить.

Answer (score 0):

Если сохранять качество то нельзя:

1) не хватит мощности процессора чтобы перекодировать битмап в JPG без сильной потери качества.

2) не хватит скорости SD карты памяти чтобы сохранить фотки большого размера.

Даже не все фотоаппараты с этим справляются, учитывая что они заточены под это, и имеют спец процессоры и прочее железо заточенные исключительно на обработку фото.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Может посоветуете как оптимизировать сохранение картинки, чтобы выиграть хотя бы несколько секунд?

Comment: @Сергей попробуйте сохранять не на карту, а на внутренний накопитель. Скорость записи намного выше, но могут возникнуть проблемы с местом.

Comment: @DeKaNszn Спасибо, попробую! Если сначала снимки просто класть в массив, а запись начинать после завершения серии фото, это серьезно повлияет на скорость (уменьшится время)?

Comment: Памяти не хватит.

Comment: @Сергей Если их хранить в памяти, то очень быстро будет `OutOfMemoryException`