# Получить изображение с камеры 30 раз в секунду. Android

Tags: java, android, камера

Реализую приложение, которое должно получать изображение с камеры на обработку 30 раз в секунду. Как лучше реализовать? Не думаю, что можно просто делать фото.

Comment: вопрос поднимался [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418245/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jpg-%D0%B2-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Базовый класс для работы с камерой, который я использовал, целиком:

```
public abstract class BaseCameraActivity extends BaseResearchActivity {
  protected static final String TAG = "Fit-Camera";

  protected SurfaceView myVideoCaptureView;
  protected Camera myCamera;

  protected abstract void initActionDetector();

  protected void initCameraCaptureSurface(int id) {
    myVideoCaptureView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(id);
    SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = myVideoCaptureView.getHolder();
    if (videoCaptureViewHolder == null) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Camera cannot be captured");
      return;
    }

    // setPreviewDisplay() does not work without this line on my old HTC Desire HD.
    // HTC One SV works perfectly.
    videoCaptureViewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    videoCaptureViewHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        stopVideo();
      }

      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      }

      public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                 int width, int height) {
        startVideo();
      }
    });
  }

  protected void startVideo() {
    if (!prepareCamera()) {
      return;
    }

    initActionDetector();
    startPreview();
  }

  protected boolean prepareCamera() {
    try {
      myCamera = openFrontFacingCamera();
      if (myCamera == null) {
        return false;
      }

      SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = (myVideoCaptureView != null) ? myVideoCaptureView.getHolder() : null;
      myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(videoCaptureViewHolder);
      myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);   // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways

      Camera.Parameters parameters = myCamera.getParameters();
      parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(30);
      parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(15000, 30000);
      parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
      parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
      parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
      myCamera.setParameters(parameters);

      logSupportedParameters(parameters);

      return true;
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
      Log.e(TAG, throwable.getLocalizedMessage(), throwable);
      return false;
    }
  }

  protected void startPreview() {
    try {
      myCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
      Log.e(TAG, throwable.getLocalizedMessage(), throwable);
      myCamera.release();
      myCamera = null;
    }
  }

  private void logSupportedParameters(@NotNull Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    if (!DebugMode.DEBUG_LOG_ON) {
      return;
    }

    List<int[]> supportedPreviewFps = parameters.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
    if (supportedPreviewFps != null) {
      for (int[] tmpRate : supportedPreviewFps) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("supportedPreviewRate: ");
        for (int i = tmpRate.length, j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          builder.append(tmpRate[j]).append(", ");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, builder.toString());
      }
    }

    List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    if (supportedPreviewSizes != null) {
      for (Camera.Size size : supportedPreviewSizes) {
        Log.d(TAG, "supportedPreviewSize.width = " + size.width + ", supportedPreviewSize.height = " + size.height);
      }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "previewFrameRate=" + parameters.getPreviewFrameRate());
  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform
  @Nullable
  private static Camera openFrontFacingCamera() {
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if (DebugMode.DEBUG_LOG_ON) {
      Log.i(TAG, "getNumberOfCameras=" + cameraCount);
    }

    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
      Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
      if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        try {
          return Camera.open(camIdx);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      return Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
      return null;
    }
  }

  private void stopVideo() {
    if (myCamera == null) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      myCamera.stopPreview();
      myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
      myCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
      myCamera.release();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
      Log.e(TAG, throwable.getLocalizedMessage(), throwable);
    } finally {
      myCamera = null;
    }
  }

  public void finish() {
    stopVideo();
    super.finish();
  }

  protected void setFrame(int id, @NotNull Bitmap bitmap) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
    Bitmap copyBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(copyBitmap);
  }
}
```

Мне нужна была front-facing камера, если есть, поэтому внутри именно эта константа. Ровно также можно получить основную камеру.